# Label not showing on if duplicate found asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

When retrieving values from database i'm checking if the value of a textbox consists in the array. The array contains retrieved values from the database. If it does contain the value it should show a label. This works until i add an else to the if statement, after that the label refuses to show.

Main Page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:MultiView ID="ManageCourseMultiView" ActiveViewIndex="1" runat="server">
            <asp:View ID="OptionsView" runat="server">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="CourseLinkButton" CommandName="SwitchViewByID" CommandArgument="ManageCourseView" runat="server">Please click here to manage your course.</asp:LinkButton>
                &nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="CourseContentLinkButton" CommandName="SwitchViewByID" CommandArgument="ManageCourseContentView" runat="server">Please click here to manage your course content.</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:HyperLink ID="CreateCourseLink" NavigateUrl="~/Instructors/CreateCourse2.aspx" runat="server">Please click here to create a course.</asp:HyperLink>
                <br />
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Course] WHERE ([CourseId] = @CourseId)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="CourseId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="ManageCourseView" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="UserIdLabel" Visible="true" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CourseId" DataSourceID="GridViewSource" Width="1072px">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseId" HeaderText="CourseId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CourseId" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName" HeaderText="CourseName" SortExpression="CourseName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ForRole" HeaderText="ForRole" SortExpression="ForRole" />
                        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Certification" HeaderText="Certification" SortExpression="Certification" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" Visible="false" HeaderText="UserId" SortExpression="UserId" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="GridViewSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Course.* FROM Course WHERE (UserId = @UserId)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UserIdLabel" Name="UserId" PropertyName="Text" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <br />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="CourseEditName" runat="server" Text="Course Name:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="CourseEditNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                            <asp:Label ID="nameerror" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false" Text="This Coursename already exists, please enter another one."></asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="CourseEditNameTextBox" ErrorMessage="Course Name cannot be empty."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="CourseEditForRoles" runat="server" Text="For Role: "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="CourseEditForRole" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Parent" Value="Parent"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Staff" Value="Staff"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Health Care PRofessional" Value="HealthPro"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ForRoleUpdate" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT RoleName FROM Roles WHERE (RoleName &lt;&gt; 'BackOffice') AND (RoleName &lt;&gt; 'Instructor')"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="CourseEditCertification" runat="server" Text="Certification: "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CourseEditCertificationCheckBox" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="CourseEditUpdate" OnClick="CourseEditUpdate_Click" runat="server" Text="Finish Editing" />
                            <asp:Button ID="CourseEditCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" Text="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Course] WHERE [CourseId] = @CourseId" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Course] ([CourseName], [ForRole], [Certification], [UserId]) VALUES (@CourseName, @ForRole, @Certification, @UserId)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Course]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Course] SET [CourseName] = @CourseName, [ForRole] = @ForRole, [Certification] = @Certification, [UserId] = @UserId WHERE [CourseId] = @CourseId">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="CourseId" Type="Int32" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="CourseName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ForRole" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Certification" Type="Boolean" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Object" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="CourseName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ForRole" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Certification" Type="Boolean" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Object" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="CourseId" Type="Int32" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="ManageCourseContentView" runat="server">
                <h2>Test</h2>
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CodeBhind:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Boolean checkboxvalue;
    string cert;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Course WHERE CourseId = '" + GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    CourseEditForRole.SelectedValue = reader["ForRole"].ToString();
                    CourseEditNameTextBox.Text = reader["CourseName"].ToString();
                    checkboxvalue = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["Certification"]);
                    cert = reader["Certification"].ToString();
                    if (cert == "False")
                    {
                        CourseEditCertificationCheckBox.Checked = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CourseEditCertificationCheckBox.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT CourseName FROM Course WHERE (CourseId = '" + GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "')";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    coursenamevalue = reader["CourseName"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        using (var command2 = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command2.CommandText = "SELECT CourseName FROM [Course] WHERE (CourseName <> '" + coursenamevalue + "')";
            using (var reader = command2.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    coursename[i] = reader["CourseName"].ToString();
                    i++;
                }
                counter = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
 protected void CourseEditUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Boolean checkboxvalue;
    string cert;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command2 = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command2.CommandText = "SELECT CourseName FROM [Course] WHERE (CourseName <> '" + coursenamevalue + "')";
            using (var reader = command2.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    coursename[i] = reader["CourseName"].ToString();
                    if (CourseEditNameTextBox.Text.Equals(reader["CourseName"].ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        //cameerror.Visible = true;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                counter = i;
            }
        }
    }
    int k = 0;

    while(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(coursename[k]))
    {
        if (coursename[k].Contains(CourseEditNameTextBox.Text))
        {
            nameerror.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            nameerror.Visible = false;
        }
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of coursename in CourseEditUpdate_Click?

Comment: coursename is of type string array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you continue in the while loop if its exist you need to break the loop because is the last item in the array is different then the text box content the label will disappear, you must do this:

```
int k = 0;

while(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(coursename[k]))
{
    if (coursename[k].Contains(CourseEditNameTextBox.Text))
    {
        nameerror.Visible = true;
        Break;
    }
    else
    {
        nameerror.Visible = false;
    }
    k++;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you heaps for this, can't believe it wasn't working because i wasn't breaking out of the loop.

Comment: Welcome :), it happen alot ;)